# upload data in SQL Postgres and getting file permissions error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to upload a table in Postgres and I am getting the error:

> ERROR:  could not open file "/Users/michaelreinhardme.com/Desktop/P9-ConsumerComplaints.csv" for reading: Permission denied
> HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
> SQL state: 42501
> Blockquote

But I have changed to permissions to Read and Right on the file, the folder my desktop is in and anywhere else I can think of. I would follow the 'HINT' but I have no idea what it means. I am working on a Mac if that is relevant. I am stumped.

Comment: `COPY` runs as the server user, so that user needs access/permissions on the file. The `HINT` is telling you to use `\copy` command in `psql`.  This runs as the client(`psql`) user and so can read the client file. For more information see [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and then search for '\copy`.

Comment: Hi and thanks. Can't I give permission to the 'server user'? I changed the file to give permission to 'Michael Reinhard' (me), the staff, and everyone. Those are the only three 'names' that come up when I ask for info on a file. Why can't I give access to the 'server user'? Is there any way to get the server user to come up in the sharing and permissions box?

Comment: How did you install Postgres? In the meantime try the `psql` command it does the same thing as `COPY`.

Comment: I am sorry to be so much trouble but I don't know how to answer your question. I installed it by downloading it from the website. That's all I know. I just used the defaults. I tried adding 'admin' to the permissions box and giving admin permission to read and write but that didn't work. I tried adding PostgresSQL but all I see is 'fetching' in the box at the bottom of the info pop-up. 

As for trying the psql command, I did try adding a backslash before my command in the query box. But I think you are suggesting something else, right? What does 'try the psql command' mean?

Comment: There are multiple choices for MacOS on the website, which one did you choose EDB, Homebrew, etc? Are you using pgAdmin4 to do your queries?

Comment: I am using pdAdmin 4. I downloaded it from EDB. There, on EDB, I chose the first choice available

Comment: Are you using the Import/Export dialog?

Comment: I don't think so. I was just trying to open it from the query window in pgAdmin 4. Did I understand your question?

Comment: Yes. Find the table you want to Import into and right click(or whatever it takes on Mac) to and then click on the `Import/Export` item. That will launch a dialog where you can select a file to import into the table.

Comment: Hey Adrian, I just found out how to do it. It seems that both the file and the folder the file is in have to have the right permissions. The Desktop, where I had my downloads, was in the Cloud to which I could not grant access (thus the endless 'fetching' icon) and needed to be moved to a folder to which I can grant access. I just moved it to the 'shared' folder and changed the permissions on that folder and everything was fine! Thanks for all your help. You really put in a lot of time on me and I appreciate it.